# Is there a way in R to calculate the gap statistic of a hierarchical cluster generated with a Bray-Curtis dissimilarity matrix?

Tags: r

I already tried both `clusGap` and `fviz_gap_stat`; both require to call the `hcut` function, however, this function doesn't allow Bray-Curtis as the metric to be used for calculating dissimilarities between observations. Therefore, I tried `vegdist` and inputed the Bray-Curtis matrix in the command with no success.

**Gap Statistic for Estimating the Number of Clusters**

```
gap_stat <- clusGap(otu_matrix,FUN=hcut,hc_func="hclust",hc_method="ward.D",isdiss=TRUE,Braymatrix,K.max = 50, B = 500)
```

```
Clustering k = 1,2,..., K.max (= 50): ..
```

> Error in if (is.na(n) || n > 65536L) stop("size cannot be NA nor exceed 65536") : 
>     missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed`

Answer (score 0):

It's been long with this question but I went through the same problem and hclust requires a dist object, so if already a symmetric distance matrix, you can use, `as.dist(otu_matrix)` and if the matrix is fine, it should work.

```r
gap_stat <- clusGap(as.dist(otu_matrix), FUN=hcut, hc_func="hclust", hc_method="ward.D", isdiss=TRUE, Braymatrix, K.max = 50, B = 500)
```